# Reusing of survived local variable in each call. UB?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-function, undefined-behavior

I'm new in C#. I encountered such code-example:

```
namespace App1
{
    delegate int Sum(int number);

    class TestAnonymusMethod
    {
        static Sum m()
        {
            int result = 0;  // is not zeroed between calls

            Sum del = delegate (int number)
            {
                for (int i = 0;  i <= number;  i++)
                    result += i;
                return result;
            };
            return del;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Sum del1 = m();

            for (int i = 1;  i <= 5;  i++)
                Console.WriteLine("Sum of {0} == {1}", i, del1(i));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Sum of 1 == 1
Sum of 2 == 4
Sum of 3 == 10
Sum of 4 == 20
Sum of 5 == 35
```

As you see, local variable `result` is not zeroed between calls. Is it "undefined behaviour"? Looks like it happens because of when scope of `result` is closed, its life time is undefined.

But what are the rules of reusing alive entities in C#? Is it the rule - "to reuse always", or there are some cases, when new one will be created instead of reusing survived old one?

Comment: Why it should be zeroed? You call "m()" method just once, so it is initialized to 0 just once.

Comment: @Evk, I've renamed question. As `result` is not `static`, it looks weird a little for me (after C++) - reusing same variable (with its current value) in each call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it "undefined behavior"?

No, it's well-defined behaviour - just not the behaviour you expect.

> Looks like it happens because of when scope of result is closed, its life time is undefined.

Nope, the lifetime of `result` is extended beyond the scope of `m()`. From the C# 5 specification section 7.15.5.1:

> When an outer variable is referenced by an anonymous function, the outer variable is said to have been *captured* by the anonymous function. Ordinarily, the lifetime of a local variable is limited to execution of the block or statement with which it is associated (§5.1.7). However, the lifetime of a captured outer variable is extended at least until the delegate or expression tree created from the anonymous function becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Thank you! But did I understand the 7.15.5.1 correct?: `result` will be guaranteed alive at least until the scope of `del1` will be closed?

Comment: @user1234567: No, until the delegate is elegible for garbage collection. `del1` is a local variable that just happens to have a reference to the delegate. You could pass the value to something else that retains a reference to the same delegate and keeps it alive. Basically, the delegate has all the state it needs, including the `result` variable. You need to think in terms of *objects* and garbage collection rather than variables and scope.